# can't add on update event with unix_timestamp func

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I got 10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~bionic db server. In my table profile I have a field with default unix_timestamp(). But when I try add this func for on update event

```
 alter table profile change `updated_at` `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

it gives me syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()' at line 1

Comment: Show the complete error message

Comment: @Akina same.   "..use near '(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())..'

Comment: Have you tried "modify" instead of "change"?

Comment: @MRonline no. pls give me link. I'm not sure you can add on update in modify command.

Comment: @Akina It's in the question. Pls look closely.

Comment: Your error is not consistent with MariaDB `10.3.9`.  Are you certain that you are not using an earlier version?

Comment: You will laugh, but the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#column-definitions) by `CREATE TABLE` -> `column definition` doesn't have `ON UPDATE` for the value - only for foreign key action.

Comment: @Akina lol)) strange. Well I convinced my boss it's too damn hard to find out how to put trigger on this column. I'll just remove ON UPDATE part (without it it works just fine =) )

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, what I typed in question is the result of "select version()". So idk.

Answer (score 0):

Check out comments.
I have two possible explations which some nice people gave in comments:
1) I have different version of mariadB
2) MariaDB doc doesn't even have on update trigger description for tables so I'm not if you even can add func for on update trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following query, which works fine with MariaDB 10.4:

```
ALTER TABLE testTable MODIFY COLUMN testCol TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

See MySQL Docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html